# Foreach loop only if date is after some point

Tags: php

I want to go to end of loop only if date is past 2013-09, so not

```
2013-08
2013-09
```

but

```
2013-10
2013-11
2013-11
2014-01
```

My loop:

```
foreach ($data as $key=>$row) {
    $date = explode('-', explode(' ', trim(explode(' ', getTime($row))[0]))[0]);
    $year = intval($date[0], 10);
    $month = intval($date[1], 10);

    if (!($year >= 2013) || !($year == 2013 && $month >= 10)) {
        continue;
    }

    echo "{$year}-{$month}\n";
}
```

It gives me dates from 2013-10-01 to 2013-12-31 but nothing past that date, why?

Input data in array goes like this (if it's hard to read from code, here you have vardump):

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '2012' (length=4)
  1 => string '12' (length=2)
  2 => string '14' (length=2)
array (size=3)
  0 => string '2012' (length=4)
  1 => string '12' (length=2)
  2 => string '15' (length=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working:

```
if (!($year >= 2013)) {
    continue;
}

if ($year == 2013) {
    if (!($month >= 10)) {
        continue;
    }
}
```